# Term for compound of carbon, hydrogen, and oxygen

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology

Is there a term for a compound of carbon, hydrogen, and oxygen?

There is hydrocarbon for a compound of carbon and hydrogen.  There is also carbohydrate but that requires the ratio of hydrogen to oxygen to be 2:1.

As well as the carbohydrates, there are many other compounds of these three elements: alcohols, aldehydes, ketones, esters, etc.  Yet, I cannot find a term for the whole group.  Have I missed something or just no need is felt for such a term?

Comment: There is no general term for this group. It's quite arbitrary to categorise organic compounds just by the elements they contain, and not useful.

Comment: @Karl Thanks.  Of course, it is not an important point but given that the term hydrocarbon is quite common, it seemed a little surprising that there was no term for this group.  I guess that hydrocarbons share a lot more properties than this group.

Comment: "hydrocarbons" (!= carbohydrates) is also only useful with an additional adjective (aliphatic, olefinic, aromatic). The group is too big and diverse, nobody talks about just plain "hydrocarbons". "Carbohydrate" is a synonym for sugars. Now that's a useful category.

Comment: @Karl Thanks again.  Just "hydrocarbon" is common outside of chemistry but I can see that it is too broad in a more serious setting.  Of course, my group with oxygen is huge.  I am fairly familiar with carbohydrates as my son studies biochemistry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no term for this group as it is too broad and diverse.  Even the narrower term hydrocarbon is usually qualified e.g. aliphatic, olefinic, aromatic.

With thanks to Karl.